# Change button labels in Android Braintree drop-in UI

Tags: android, braintree

I'm using V2 of the dropin UI for Android.
I was looking for a way to customize it a little bit, i.e. renaming buttons and adding a summary description. However, looking at the official [V2 documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization/android/v1) there was nothing like it. Weird. Then, by accident I stumbled upon the [V1 documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization/android/v1) and it supports exactly what I want to do:

```
Customization customization = new Customization.CustomizationBuilder()
  .primaryDescription("Cart")
  .secondaryDescription("3 Items")
  .amount("$35")
  .submitButtonText("Purchase")
  .build();

intent.putExtra(BraintreePaymentActivity.EXTRA_CUSTOMIZATION, customization);
```

Has this accidentally been omitted from the V2 documentation(seems like a major takeaway if not)? If yes, how do I use it? Should I use V1 instead if I want this sort of workflow?

Comment: I just want to show the amount I'm going to charge in that UI.  Something like .amount("$35"). Do you have any idea how to do it ? have you found your way ?

Comment: I didn't find a way. It looks like they removed this feature and didn't replace it.

Answer (score 0):

V2 is also customizable, as [doc](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/overview/android/v2) says:

> If the Drop-in UI doesn't fit your needs, develop your own custom
>   integration using our client SDKs to accept credit cards, PayPal, and
>   other available payment method types

And [this is a related doc about paypal](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/android/v2#using-a-custom-ui)

Comment: I'm talking about drop-in specifically. I know I could just roll my own UI for all of this but I only want to make small changes to the out-of-the-box drop-in UI which was possible in V1 and seems to have been removed for V2. That's why I'm confused.